# System equation and varwidth

Tags: cases, varwidth

I have two question:
How can I left-align the equation system?
How can I middle-align (vertical) the item bullet?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage[
      a4paper,
      margin=15mm,
      bindingoffset=2mm,
      heightrounded,
    ]{geometry}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{varwidth}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newif\ifodd
    \oddtrue
    \newcommand\odd{\oddtrue\item}
    \newcommand\pair{\oddfalse\item}

    \begin{document}
    \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}
    \colorbox{white}{%
      \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}
      TRIGONOMETRIA
      \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,label={\ifodd\color{black}\else\color{blue}\fi\textbullet}]
     \odd $\sin^{2} \alpha + \cos^{2} \alpha = 1$

  \pair \textcolor{blue}{$\tan \alpha = \dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$}

  \odd $\sin \alpha + \beta = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha$

  \pair \textcolor{blue}{$\cos \alpha + \beta = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$}

  \odd $\tan \alpha + \beta = \dfrac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta}$

  \pair \textcolor{blue}{$\sin \alpha - \beta = \sin \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \beta \cos \alpha$}

  \odd $\cos \alpha - \beta = \cos \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \alpha \sin \beta$

  \pair \textcolor{blue}{$\tan \alpha - \beta = \dfrac{\tan \alpha - \tan \beta}{1 + \tan \alpha \tan \beta}$}

  \odd $\sec \alpha = \dfrac{1}{\cos \alpha}$

  \pair \textcolor{blue}{$\dfrac{\sin^{2} \alpha}{\cos^{2} \alpha} + 1 = \tan^{2} \alpha + 1 = \sec^{2} \alpha$}

  \odd \[ \cos 2\alpha =\begin{cases}
               \cos^{2} \alpha - \sin^{2} \alpha\\
               2 \cos^{2} \alpha - 1\\
               1 - \sin^{2} \alpha
            \end{cases}
    \]

      \end{itemize}
      \end{varwidth}%
    }\endgroup
    \end{document}
```

The equation system is the last one
[image]

Comment: your equations are left aligned. for last equation use `$ ... $` instead `\[ ... \]`. by the way, what is purposes `varwidth` and invisible box? And, welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: is now your problem solved? if not, please explain, why you use `varwidth`, `colorbox`, what you mean with "left aligned"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is is solved by comment.

Comment: This what I mean with "left aligned": http://imgur.com/zMrVPwA